# Move one div on click of another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to use jquery to move one div (that'll be absolutely positioned off screen) to a specific part of it's parent element when an a tag is clicked.

```
<div id="casestudy4" class="newboxes2">
                                <div class="paperclip"></div>
                                <p>text here</p>

                            </div> <!-- end div casestudy4 -->
```

Basically .paperclip is absolutely positioned left:25%; top:-2000px; and I'd like it to move down when the link is clicked.

Comment: I'm guessing by link, you mean the text in the `<p>...</p>` tag

Comment: where is the link? and which method u use to control this animation?

Comment: ah! a downvote without reason...? ( ._.)

Comment: May I ask why you have a top:-2000px; positioned div? Why not just display:none; ?

Comment: for animation purposes, maybe...

Comment: Yes, for animation purposes, it's already in a div with display:none, which opens when the link is pressed, I'd then like the other div(paperclip) to 'drop down'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#move").click(function () {
                $(".paperclip").animate({
                    top: "+=500px"
                }, 5000);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <a href="#" id="move">move</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm really after more of an animated effect.

Comment: @andy: Updated with animation

Answer (score 0):

you may use this to hide the div when you click the link

```
$(selector).click(function(){
   $('.paperclip').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link is the paragraph, this is a solution.

```
$("#casestudy4 > p:first-child").click(function() {
  $("#casestudy4 > .paperclip").css("top", "500px");
}
```

Obviously, you will have to properly target the link and properly specify what *"down"* means instead of `500px`.